# Cannot get data from Azure Sql Server in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, database, azure

I am trying to connect to azure sql server from my excel.

However, I can only see Azure data explorer in the GetData -> Azure tab.

Unlike my other excel installed in a different computer, I cannot see any other azure services that I can get data from.

I tried uninstalling and installing back to the lastest 2016 Excel but had no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeqJW.png)

Comment: Hello Simon, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please reference this document: [Connect Excel to a database in Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance, and create a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-excel):

```
You can connect Excel to a database and then import data and create tables and charts based on values in the database. In this tutorial you will set up the connection between Excel and a database table, save the file that stores data and the connection information for Excel, and then create a pivot chart from the database values.
```

I use Excel 2016 and also don't have **From** **Azure SQL Database**:
[image]

But `Get Extra Data`-->`From Other Source`-->`From SQL Server` also works with Azure SQL database.
For example, I get the table test5 data from my Azure SQL database:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** make sure you have added IP address to the firewall for your current computer.

Hope this helps.